# C++ project can be compiled on Windows in Visual Studio but can not be compiled with the same sources on Raspberry Pi 4B using Code Blocks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, codeblocks

I have created a videogame for Raspberry Pi. I have developed it using Visual Studio on Windows 10 but when I try to create a Code Blocks project on Raspberry Pi (Raspberry Pi OS 32 bit) and add my sources to this project one source file can not be compiled in Code Blocks IDE and VS Code. Code Blocks on Windows 10 can not also compile this code
The minimal reproducible example is below. Launcher:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include "FightersController.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    FightersController fightersController;
    int randomDir = fightersController.generateRandomDirectionInCrosshairVisibleArea();
    std::cout << "Random generated direction is " + std::to_string(randomDir) << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Class FightersController - header:

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>   

class FightersController
{
public:
    FightersController();
    ~FightersController();
    int generateRandomDirectionInCrosshairVisibleArea();

private:
    std::vector<int>* mutDirectionList = nullptr;     //mutable list of the directions
    const static int LEFT_DIR = 2;
    const static int RIGHT_DIR = 4;
    const static int UP_DIR = 3;
    const static int DOWN_DIR = 1;
    void fillMutDirList();
};
```

Class FightersController - source:

```
#include "FightersController.h"

FightersController::FightersController() {
    mutDirectionList = new std::vector<int>();
}

FightersController::~FightersController() {
    delete mutDirectionList;
}

int FightersController::generateRandomDirectionInCrosshairVisibleArea() {
    fillMutDirList();
    mutDirectionList->erase(std::remove(mutDirectionList->begin(), mutDirectionList->end(), UP_DIR), mutDirectionList->end());
    return 0;
}

void FightersController::fillMutDirList() {
    mutDirectionList->clear();
    mutDirectionList->insert(mutDirectionList->begin(), DOWN_DIR);
    mutDirectionList->insert(mutDirectionList->begin(), LEFT_DIR);
    mutDirectionList->insert(mutDirectionList->begin(), UP_DIR);
    mutDirectionList->insert(mutDirectionList->begin(), RIGHT_DIR);
}
```

And I get the next error in the Build log of the CodeBlocks (Visual Studio compiles without problems):

> ||=== Build: Debug in Error_finding_codeblocks (compiler: GNU GCC
> Compiler) ===|
> C:\Others\GD\Workspace\tests\Error_finding_codeblocks\src\FightersController.cpp||In
> member function 'int
> FightersController::generateRandomDirectionInCrosshairVisibleArea()':|
> C:\Others\GD\Workspace\tests\Error_finding_codeblocks\src\FightersController.cpp|13|error:
> cannot convert 'std::vector::iterator' {aka
> '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector >'} to 'const
> char*'|
> C:\КД\Мусор\GD\Software\codeblocks-20.03mingw-nosetup\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h|676|note:   initializing argument 1 of 'int remove(const char*)'| ||=== Build
> finished: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: `mutDirectionList = new std::vector<int>();` -- One question -- why are you using `new` to create vectors?   Why are your `vector` member variables pointers, instead of simply `std::vector<whatever> x;`?  C++ is not Java.  Also, which line in all of this code is line 203?

Comment: Also, you should post a [mcve].  It should be as simple as declaring a vector, and calling the erase-remove idiom on that vector.   You don't need all of this code, unless there is a typo in your code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think it is not important for this class and I can change it through vector of the integer variables. Do you think the problem is in this? Are there some differences between compilers? The problem lines of code are located in the function: int FightersController::generateRandomDirectionInCrosshairVisibleArea(); When I hide this lines of code the compiler shows errors in the function: void FightersController::fillMutDirList(). It can not see my constants: DOWN_DIR, UP_DIR and so on to fill my vector with values

Comment: The problem with your question is that no one is going to be able to compile your code to see the error, since again, it is not a [mcve].  I suggest you remove all the code, and add a little at a time, each time compiling the small amount of code.  Keep adding code until the compilation breaks -- then that last piece of code you added is causing the issue.  To be honest, that should have been the first thing any programmer would have done, and that is to start out clean with hardly any code, compile, keep adding code until the compilation breaks.

Comment: Also, it would have been surprising to *not* see a compilation issue, given all of this code.  You would have been lucky to see a successful compilation from the start after changing platforms, and you should have been prepared for this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, this way is correct. I will try to create a clear project and extract some pieces of code from my game to compile it direct on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have simplified my code. It doesn't run also on Windows if I use CodeBlocks. Is that something wrong with the compiller?

Answer (score 0):

> note: initializing argument 1 of 'int remove(const char*)'

The issue seems to be that you are calling `std::remove`, but there are two versions of this function available in the C++ standard library, and neither has anything to do with the other.

1. [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) from `<algorithm>`, and
2. [std::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) from `<cstdio>`.

Since you want to use `std::remove` from `<algorithm>`, you should explicitly include `<algorithm>`, as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6chcG8o91).

This is why it is important to include all headers that are relevant to the module being compiled, even if your compiler *may* include the header implicitly.

Going to another platform, you see that relying on the compiler to supply the "missing" headers will result in wasted time and effort.

Comment: If I right understood the difference was not in operating systems but in compilers. GCC doesn't include by default <algorithm> header. I have added #include <algorithm>and the compiler shows me my next errors: the source file doesn't see  my four const static int constants from the header. I have remove static and leaved only const int LEFT_DIR = 2, const int RIGHT_DIR = 4; and so on and it works. Does it also the GCC problem?

Comment: You can still have `static` if you changed it to `constexpr static int LEFT_DIR = 2;`, plus the other ones you mentioned.  The answer directly addresses the error I mentioned, and probably you should open another question, but using the fixed code mentioned in this answer (since we do not know how many more errors you actually have).  Also, [here is a much better version of the code you have now](https://godbolt.org/z/zx4WWdab6).